# Xamarin.Forms App Crashes On Click Event Handler

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have created a small app using Visual Studio for Mac for iOS with Xamarin Forms. It has three XAML pages. Since this application intends to send message which can not be accomplished using simulator, therefore, I tried using Xamarin Live on my iPhone. The application is installed and shows OK on iPhone Xamarin Live but when I tap on a button on home page it takes us to Message page exactly as intended. There is a send message button on the Message page, when this button is clicked an exception shows up stating 'Uncaught Exception: The index was out of bounds of the array (IndexOutOfRangeException)'. It appears as if it is a problem with page stack, but unfortunately, I am not able to nail it down. Below is the code.

Click Handler on the Home Page

```
if (xMessagePage == null)
        xMessagePage = new xMessagePage();
    try
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(xMessagePage);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayAlert("BtnMessage_Clicked", ex.Message, "OK");
    }
```

Click Handler on the message page which tries to bring up the UIActivityViewController

```
public void BtnMessage_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs eArgs)
{
    uMessageController umc = new uMessageController();

    try
    {
         umc.SendTextMessage("en-us", eMessageType.Text);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        uShareMessages.ShowMessageBox("Message_Clicked", ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
    }
}

void uMessageController::SendTextMessage(string strTextMsg, "en-us", eMessageType.Text)
{
try
{
string strDefaultMsg = "MyTest Message1"
string strDefAttachmentName = "NYC";
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(strTextMsg))
strTextMsg = strDefaultMsg;
string strTextMsg1 = uShareMessages.GetMessageString(strCulture);
string existingSound = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(strDefAttachmentName, "mp3");

            var remFileUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(existingSound);

            lstMessageItems = new System.Collections.Generic.List<NSObject> { new NSString(strTextMsg1 ?? string.Empty) };
            lstMessageItems.Add(remFileUrl);
            UIActivityViewController avController = new UIActivityViewController(lstMessageItems.ToArray(), null);

            avController.ExcludedActivityTypes = vcActivitiesExcluded;
            avController.CompletionWithItemsHandler = ActivityViewController_CompletionHandler;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(avController, true, null);

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            uShareMessages.ShowMessageBox("SendTextMessage", ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Paraclete

Comment: why aren't you just deploying the app to your phone directly?

Comment: Jason:Becuase there is no such option for the attached device in the Tools->Devices. Also once I did and deleted the app mistakenly and then Visual Studio was not able to push the app back to phone.

Comment: I would really focus on solving that problem first.  I don't believe that Live Player is intended for full app debugging like you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but debugging on an iPhone directly through my mac from my PC running Visual Studio 2017